# Rails select, group, having, count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, group-by, having

I want to get the count of how many appointments are under 1 hr, 1 to 2 hrs and over 2 hours.

```
Appointment
.select("id, EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (check_out_at - check_in_at)) as minutes")
.group("id, minutes")
.having("count('minutes') < 60")
.count
```

The count method return the following exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: ...EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (check_out_at - check_in_at)) as minutes...
```

Comment: Can you post the full SQL query generated? Also, I assume you are using PostgreSQL, right? (since the `PG::SyntaxError` in the output)

Comment: @user1262904 did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` is primary key, you neither need `group by` nor `having`. You can simply do this to get count of appointments under 1 hour:

```
Appointment.where("(EXTRACT(epoch FROM (check_out_at - check_in_at))) < 3600").count
```

To get count of all appointments grouped by hour, you can do this:

```
Appointment.group("Floor(Extract(epoch from (check_out_at - check_in_at))/3600)").count
```

The output would be like:

```
{0.0=>1, 2.0=>31, 3.0=>11}
```

meaning 1 appointment between 0-1 hour, 31 are between 2-3 hours and so on.